# Encrypt database connection .env in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, encryption, laravel-5

When we put `laravel` project to `localhost`. Anyone can view our project .env file and they can view our database password `DB_USERNAME=` `DB_PASSWORD=` how can we encrypt it??

Comment: If the server can decrypt it, so can anybody with access to the server, so what is the point?

Comment: No you just have to give right permission to .env file so no one can acess accept your server. eg 644

Comment: i mean i want to encrypt that file or encrypt DB_PASSWORD= and DB_USERNAME how can??

Comment: Well if anyone can view your .env file then maybe you should block access to the .env file from everyone except the webserver.

Comment: @jeroen if someone can access to server and then they can view our database password

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, is that a question?

Comment: @apokryfos so we can't encrypt that file we only block access by grant permission in server right?

Comment: You can encrypt the file, but it's the wrong approach to take and will just shift the problem elsewhere. Using permissions is the correct way to do this. That's what permissions are there for.

Comment: @Heshan You need to restrict access to the server itself because anybody who can run your project directly from the server / the command line can dump your database connection variables.

Comment: @jeroen the question is  if someone can access to server and then they can view our database password i want to ebcrypt .env file or DB password if someone can access to server but they can read my .env file how can??

Comment: @Heshan You are completely missing the points of the above comments...

Comment: @jeroen okay i see the only one way is we need to restrict our connection to the server no way to encrypt the DB password or .env file

Answer (score 0):

You can just set a encrypted string as password in the '.env' file and decrypt it in your code. But I dont think that it will increase the security level on your system. Much more important is set the right configuration on the server (permissions, file locations, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can access environment variables using $_SERVER , $_ENV (PHP super global variables) and env helper and after this encrypt your environment variables value and decrypt when assign value to a variable . For more information [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration)

If you have not enough time than you also find this package to make it easy to add encrypted environment variables [BaglerIT package](https://github.com/BaglerIT/envariable)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

In your database.php:

```
use Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter;
$key = 'a3c4b614a1f072e0f968c2712a36323f'; //A md5 hash (length 32)
$encrypter = new Encrypter($key, 'AES-256-CBC');
//encrypt test:
//$str = $encrypter->encryptString('your_password');
//die($str);
...
'connections' => [
        'oracle' => [
            ...
            'password' => $encrypter->decryptString(env('DB_PASSWORD')),
            ...
        ],
...
```

then you can set DB_PASSWORD in your .env file encrypted as this:

```
// Code to get the encrypted value
use Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter;
$key = 'a3c4b614a1f072e0f968c2712a36323f'; // same key is used for decrypt
$encrypter = new Encrypter($key, 'AES-256-CBC'); // same key and cipher used for decrypt
$str = $encrypter->encryptString('your_password'); // <- THIS IS YOUR DB_PASSWORD VALUE
```